# How to access members of a class with dynamic names Cocos2d-x C++

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x

I have some numbers in my header that I want to access in the code like this.

```
int _number0;
int _number1;
```

Then in implementation

```
_number0 = 10;
_number1 = 20;

int i;
for(i=0; i<2, i++){
    auto number = _number+i; //This is where I'm lost, how to do the right part right in order to get this int by its name created from a String + an Integer.
    CCLOG("Number: %i", number); //Output Number: 10 // Number: 20
}
```

I was thinking on a pseudo code like this:

```
auto number = dynamic_cast<Int*>(this->findTheMemberWithName("level%i",i));
```

Is there any way to do something like this in C++?

Thanks for any guideline. Greetings.

Comment: Make `_number` an array, and use the number at the end as its index?  For example, instead of having `int _number0` and `int _number1`, you could have `int _number[2]` or `std::array<int, 2> _number`.  Then, assign `_number[0] = 10;` and `_number[1] = 20;`.  With this, `auto number = _number[i];` would let you access each one in your loop.

Comment: Or maybe you could use a `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> _numbers;`, and access each as, say, `auto number = _numbers["_number" + std::to_string(i)];`.

Comment: Out of these, the first is _probably_ more efficient, depending on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @JustinTime Do this as I want to do this seems that is not a possible way to go, so a workaround is the way to go. I really like the second way, but I went with the array. Thanks for your time. Greetings

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think std::map should fulfill your requirement.

P.S:In fact, why don't you use array or vector to do the job? It is really not a good idea to make up the parameter names in CPP.